# Why can't I see my phone screen in landscape with sunglasses?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm using a OnePlusOne and while using my sunglasses I can see the phone screen in portrait mode, however if I rotate the screen to landscape I can't see anything at all.

My sunglasses are polarized.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: The screen of your phone emits polarized light. Polarized sunglasses will filter out light that is not polarized the right way.

Comment: related aviation question: [Why is it hard to see G1000 with sunglasses?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/18731/why-is-it-hard-to-see-g1000-with-sunglasses)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screen of your phone uses a polarizing screens as well. When you hold you phone in portrait mode, the screens are oriented in the same direction so you can see the image. When you rotate it 90deg, the screens are not aligned and light cannot pass.